# How to use Google search in a new tab on Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm using the latest release of Edge (the Chromium-based one); I configured Google as my home page and as my search engine, but I'm still stuck with Bing search when opening a new tab.

Is there any way to use Google search in a new tab, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but just as Chrome forces the Google homepage on a new tab, Edge forces the Copilot on a new tab.

**Just use the **address bar** for your searches**, and you'll always have Google.

To completely remove the Copilot, you'll need to use an extension, such as "[New Tab Changer](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/new-tab-changer/dlbnebcbaeajdpekcdhmcgdhoodcjpeg)" or "[Blank new page](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/blank-new-tab-page-whit/kakgoomeaegcolfmaaogfmifnnmllpkm)"

**Workarounds without Extensions:**

- add `google.com` to your favorites bar, and use `Ctrl+Shift+Left Click` to open a new tab
- Hit `Ctrl+t` for a new tab, then click on the `Home` button to go to Google.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like there is no workaround (and I can of course see why Microsoft wouldn't give us one). Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it looks like MS only allows to only change the ones you mentioned in the Edge settings:

edge://settings/search?search=default

But, there are extensions that allows you to change the new tab page search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Chrometana can redirect every bing search to other preffered search engine.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrometana-redirect-bing/kaicbfmipfpfpjmlbpejaoaflfdnabnc

Answer (score 0):

There are extensions that can do that (if Microsoft hasn't blocked them too):

- [New Tab Changer](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/new-tab-changer/dlbnebcbaeajdpekcdhmcgdhoodcjpeg)
- [Custom New Tab Page](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/custom-new-tab-page/ljabenhdllbfiglklhlmoecabdkmkjkp)
- [New Google Tab](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/new-google-tab/plkbiaiofflbcpfahbgmfhfmdchigfcb?hl=en-GB)